# What is maximum length of the title in Data Table? Not column header

Tags: usability, user-expectation, data-tables, title

Considering it is Desktop applicaiton, Do we need to truncate the length, bring it to second line or ellipsis?[image: Reference]

Comment: My answer would have been "refer to your corporate style guide - if you don't have a corporate styleguide then start one with this. You also haven't given enough variables for us to judge that validity of an answer: How big are the tables, what font size are you using, how likely are long titles, how long is the longest title likely to be, can this be controlled at CMS level..."

Comment: Also @JonW, I don't believe this is a duplicate question. The question you posted is about column headers, but this question is about the table heading.

Comment: The question title and the question body are asking two different things. Do you want to know the best length of the title? Or are you asking how to handle long titles?

Comment: Best length and how do you handle the best length

Comment: @AndrewMartin How big are the tables - full width                                    how likely are long titles - this is worst case scenario, today longest one is around 40-50% of the data table

Comment: Full width of what? I'm sitting here at a 27" cinema display - 50% of that is longer than this comment.

Comment: @AndrewMartin ask is for Desktop, mentioned in question

Comment: But my desktop is a 27" screen. The guys in out accounts department have 19" desktop screens. Saying that it's full width of a desktop is like saying it's as long as a peice of string.

Answer (score 2):

### Bring it to the second line

This has a number of benefits over the other options:

- **No ambiguous titles**

  - Titles with similar beginnings might look identical when they're truncated.
- **Decreased cognitive load**

  - Searching for a way to reveal the full title will increase the user's cognitive load.
- **Maximum length becomes irrelevant**

  - Sometimes a title needs to be long to provide enough information on context.
- **User does not miss out on any important information**

  - If the title contains information which is important, the user might not see this if the title is truncated.

I believe the only reason to truncate the title is **if you're limited for space**, such as in the title bar of a window.

However, there does not appear to be any fixed constraints on your title area, so displaying the title on multiple lines is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. Also would like to know what is the max. characters allowed per line? what percent of screen can it occupy? is there any guidelines for that

Comment: I've never heard of any formal guidelines regarding that, but in your case it would make sense simply to make it fill the available space rather than giving it a fixed length.